# Divide space into 3 parallel blocks

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I expect `li` inside `ul` to be divided into 3 parallel lists of elements next to each other. However, the list appears in a straight list.

I expected `col-xs-3` to do the job but it does not seem to work. Suggestions to fix this?

```
return <div id="col_sub_1">
  <ul className="col-xs-3 sub-menu-width ">
  {
    childitem.map(function(subcat,subcatindex){
      {/*--LEAF WHEN NO CHILD ELEMENTS */}
      return  <li>
      {
        subcat.id !=54 ? <a className="event_menu_item_desktop"><span> {subcat.name}</span></a> : null
      </li>
    })
  }
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your code seems to be missing a `}`. Also, you may want to know that `.filter` exists, so you're not doing all those ternary checks: `childitem.filter(v => v.id !== 54).map( item => <li><a className="...">{item.name}</a></li>);` - One line, no need for ternaries, far easier to work with. As for "why it doesn't work": what made you think that class should work (e.g. what are you using, is that loading, is CSS getting actually applied, does it work in plain HTML rather than JSX react? etc)

Comment: It is getting loaded and applied. Just that it's not aligning the elements as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `col-xs-3` to `<li>` tag but not to `<ul>` element. Also You are not properly closed expression.

Keep in mind always that you need to add unique key to the top element inside loop in react. Try this

```
return <div id="col_sub_1">
  <ul className="sub-menu-width ">
  {
    childitem.map((subcat,subcatindex) => (
      <li key={subcat.id} className="col-xs-3">
      {subcat.id !=54 ? <a className="event_menu_item_desktop"><span> {subcat.name}</span></a> : null}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with explanation. Please take a look at my updated answer. Also please upvote my answer as you are accepted